# request sql on cakephp

Tags: sql, cakephp

I'm trying to execute a very long and complex sql request on cakephp . from the documentation I found 2 solution. the first is to call connection manager and pass my request as a string the second is to execute it by php. my problem is that the request is so complex that I couldn't find the proper way on php.

this is my request :

```
select * from flight_schedules as fs left join weekly_schedules as ws on fs.code = ws.code left join structures as s on fs.structure_ref = s.id
where fs.c_code = "xxx" 
and DATE_FORMAT(fs.flight_start, '%Y-%m-%d') <= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d')
and DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%H:%i:%s') >= DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(fs.flight_start,INTERVAL 1 HOUR) , '%H:%i:%s')
and DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%H:%i:%s') <= DATE_FORMAT(fs.flight_end, '%H:%i:%s')
and ( DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(fs.flight_start, '%Y-%m-%d') and DATE_FORMAT(fs.flight_end, '%Y-%m-%d'))
or ( fs.flight_end IS NULL
and (DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) + ws.monday = 3
or DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) + ws.tuesday = 4
or DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) + ws.wednesday = 5
or DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) + ws.thursday = 6
or DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) + ws.friday = 7
or DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) + ws.saturday = 8
or DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) + ws.sunday = 2 ))
order by DATE_FORMAT(fs.flight_start, '%H:%i:%s') LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I think, doesn't matter either you use model or raw sql query. if you want to  use as a raw query, you can pass something like `'%s'` and `$this->YourModel->query(sprintf($sql,$param))`

Comment: Right now Im using raw sql query and to pass params I'm using something like ': c_code' for example. but I want to use the model not the sql query and I couldn't change it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this;

```
 "conditions" => [
    "fs.c_code" => "xxx",
    "DATE_FORMAT(fs.flight_start, '%Y-%m-%d') <= " =>  "DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d')",
    "DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%H:%i:%s') >= " =>  "DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(fs.flight_start,INTERVAL 1 HOUR) , '%H:%i:%s')",
    "DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%H:%i:%s')" => "DATE_FORMAT(fs.flight_end, '%H:%i:%s')",
    "DATE_FORMAT(fs.flight_start, '%Y-%m-%d')  <= " => "(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d')",
    "DATE_FORMAT(fs.flight_end, '%Y-%m-%d')  >= " => "(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d')",
    "OR" => [
        "fs.flight_end" => null,
        [
            "DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) + ws.monday" => 3,
            "OR"=>[
                "DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) + ws.tuesday" => 4,
                "DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) + ws.wednesday" => 5,
                "DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) + ws.thursday" => 6,
                "DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) + ws.friday" => 7,
                "DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) + ws.saturday" => 8,
                "DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) + ws.sunday" => 2
            ]
        ],

    ]
],
//DO ORDER AND LIMIT HERE
```

Sorry, I forget to wrap it. Do check update one.

Comment: That cannot work, as the right hand side value of `key => value` conditions is subject to casting/escaping, so it will end up as quoted string literals, ie this would create SQL like `DATE_FORMAT(fs.flight_start, '%Y-%m-%d') <= 'DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), \'%Y-%m-%d\')'`. @chogath

Comment: @ndm Yes, this code might not be worked. I just shown how to convert SQL to cakephp's query. Amended may be needed.